# CMake: Use generators for other platforms. How?

Tags: linux, cmake

Using CMake, how can one generate Visual Studio project files on Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. You have to run CMake on Windows to generate for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you would use the Windows [GUI program](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/runningcmake.html) and select what to generate for. But if you do want to generate them on Linux perhaps you could use wine/crossover to run the Windows generator program.

If you want to have the Visual Studio project files then you will need a Windows machine to compile them in any case. Why not just generate them there as well?

I'm running CMake 2.8.6 and these are the generators I have available:

```
Unix Makefiles              = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
Xcode                       = Generate Xcode project files.
CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles
                            = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
KDevelop3                   = Generates KDevelop 3 project files.
KDevelop3 - Unix Makefiles  = Generates KDevelop 3 project files.
```

Therefore, **no** generator for Visual Studio.

Comment: Because I'm just giving a presentation about CMake and want to demo this feature. So you are sure, that windows generators are only available on windows??

Comment: Without doing some hacking, then yes, I'm sure that it is not available.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, this is not supported by CMake (current version 2.8.6).