# Generate project files for MonoDevelop using CMake

Tags: c++, c, mono, cmake, monodevelop

I have used Visual C++ for a while and set up my project to build using CMake. I was considering using an open source alternative IDE, MonoDevelop. However, I can't open vcxproj files using MonoDevelop, which are generated by CMake for Visual Studio and I don't see any option for MonoDevelop. Is there a way to have CMake build the project files for Mono?

Comment: Seems there is currently no generator in CMake that handles Mono project files. I have no clue about Mono, but I would think unless it can import some other project files (like Makefiles) you're out of luck :(

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the CMake recipe you are using to generate your projects?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate visual studio files, MonoDevelop should handle them but there may be problems.

Comment: I'm trying this. It appears cmake only generates Visual Studio files on Windows. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263612/cmake-use-generators-for-other-platforms-how